# How can I make greasemonkey search only within a table

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Below is my code and currently it searches the whole webpage. I'm trying to figure out how to make it search only within a table. (There is only one table on the page).

Any help would be appreciated.

```
var TargetLink              = $("a:contains('gg')");
var TargetSink              = $("a:contains('u')");

if (TargetLink  &&  TargetLink.length)
{
window.location.href    = TargetLink[0].href;
} 
else if (TargetSink  &&  TargetSink.length) 
{
window.location.href    = TargetSink[0].href;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var TargetLink              = $("table a:contains('gg')");
var TargetSink              = $("table a:contains('u')");
```

**EDIT:**
You say there is only one table on the page. Do you absolutely know there will only ever be one table? Even if you think the answer is yes, I would try and add an id or class selector so that things won't break in the future.

Also, the following code can be simplified:

```
if (TargetLink  &&  TargetLink.length)
```

to:

```
if (TargetLink.length)
```

---

Re: `"could I combine those 2 variables into 1"`:

Use a comma in the selector, like so:

```
//--- Need more of the HTML structure for a better selector.
var TargetLink              = $("table")
                            .find ("a:contains('gg'), a:contains('u')")
                            ;
if (TargetLink.length) {
    window.location.href    = TargetLink[0].href;
}
```

If both kind of links are found, `'gg'` will be used (first).

Comment: Wow that was  really fast response thank you.
That is just what I was looking for!
While I'm here how could I combine those 2 variables into 1?
I've tried like 
    var TargetSink              = $("table a:contains('u', 'gg')");
and a few other similar changes but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Oh I didn't see the Edit part but Yes it is possible that in the future there will be more than one table.